# Xcode - Connect a Date Picker and a Time Picker to the same NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdate, uidatepicker

I have a Time Picker and a Date Picker.

How to get the time included with the date in same NSDate?

I need the time between 2 dates (including time) How?

I have the code for getting time between dates, i just need help to include the time.

Comment: NSDate is immutable.  Both pickers work by storing pointers to NEW objects when selection is done.  They can't both modify the "same" object at the same time.

Comment: Ok, but how should i do for storing a Date included with time?

Comment: That requires programming.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard? Do you just want a picker that does both?

Comment: Ok, what code? Yes, i'm using storyboard. but want the datepicker including year.

Answer (score 1):

By default, a UIDatePicker is set to allow the user to choose a Date and a Time. The `mode` can be set to either `Date`, `Time` or `Date and Time`. As long as the mode of your UIDatePicker is set to `Date and Time` it will set both the date and time in the linked NSDate object.

If you **really** want to have two separate UIDatePickers, one set to `Date` and the other to `Time` then you will need to link them to two different NSDate objects and then have code behind to combine the two NSDates into a single NSDate using something like the code here [Problem combining a date and a time into a single NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979462/problem-combining-a-date-and-a-time-into-a-single-nsdate)